# Diff an Array (without modifying original arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

**OBJECTIVE**

I am trying to highlight the dfferences between two arrays. Please note that arr1 and arr2 will vary in length and have multiple types present (strings and numbers).

**MY CODE**

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var diffArr = [];

  if (arr1.length >= arr2.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) < 0) {
          diffArr.push(arr1[i]);
          }
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[j]) < 0) {
        diffArr.push(arr2[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return diffArr;
}
```

**ISSUES**

```
diff([1, 2, 'cat', 'fish'], [1, 2, 3,'dog']); //returns only ['cat', 'fish']
```

*I am pretty sure that my code is only returning the duplicates in one of the arrays via diffArr.push (even if there are unique values in both arrays). However, I am unsure how to overcome this.*

**My references**

[Removes Duplicates from Javascript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

[Removed Duplicates from an Array Quickly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60128/removing-duplicates-from-an-array-quickly)

[Javascript Array Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: @Donal I dont think that this is true - indexOf() can be used for arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code currently only crawls through one array (let's call it A) and pushes in all the A values that don't exist in B. You never go the other way and push in the B values that don't exist in A. There's also no need to have different behavior based on which array is longer. Here is the final answer in a simple way:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var diffArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) < 0) diffArr.push(arr1[i]);
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[j]) < 0) diffArr.push(arr2[j]);
  }
  return diffArr;
}
```

And in a slightly more functional way:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var elsIn1Not2 = arr1.filter(function(el){ return arr2.indexOf(el) < 0; });
  var elsIn2Not1 = arr2.filter(function(el){ return arr1.indexOf(el) < 0; });
  return elsIn1Not2.concat(elsIn2Not1);
}
```

Both functions return `[ 'cat', 'fish', 3, 'dog' ]` for your example.

Comment: Thank you for this - I've been struggling with developing a more functional way of programming. I've been having trouble specifically with .filter() (the MDN example isn't great). 

Upvoted and labeled as the correct answer!

Comment: Thanks. :-) If you really want to make it concise, you could change `return arr2.indexOf(el) < 0;` to `return !~arr2.indexOf(el`. ;-) That might just be the only mainstream use of the `~` operator (bitwise NOT)…

Answer (score 0):

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  var diffArr = {};

  if (arr1.length >= arr2.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) < 0) {
          diffArr[arr1[i]] = 1;
          }
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[j]) < 0) {
        diffArr[arr2[j]] = 2;
      }
    }
  }
  return diffArr.keys();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the author's question, which seems to be "how can I get an array of all the elements not shared by both arrays." If you keep that if-else, then you'll only ever get a one-way diff.